# Are there any vars that Ansible can merge?

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

Today I noticed that Ansible won't merge vars.

For example when I have something like

```
---
lvm_roles:
  postgresql:
    size: '10g'
    path: '/var/lib/postgresql'
```

And in another place I have for example

```
---
lvm_roles:
  sonarqube:
    size: '10g'
    path: '/opt/sonarqube'
```

Ansible won't merge these facts. I am not sure about precedence but I think the first one wins. Without errors or warnings. IMHO a dangerous feature for a configuration management tool.

Are there any vars that Ansible can merge? Lists and hash won't work. Is there a workaround of some sort for this?

This is a significant shortcoming of Ansible. Because "facts" can be dependent on what you are provisioning. The inability to merge "facts" make it necessary to hard code and duplicate the stuff that you wan't to be configurable.

For example when I create one file with

```
lvm_roles:
  postgresql:
    size: '10g'
    path: '{{ postgresql_home }}'
  sonarqube:
    size: '10g'
    path: '{{ sonar_home }}'
```

This will not work because `sonar_home` is not defined on de postgresql node. On the the sonarqube node, `postgresql_home` is not defined. The ability to flexibly use vars is greatly impacted if merging is not possible.

Comment: You simply could use group vars. PostgreSQL variables on group of postgres servers and Sonarqube variables on group of sonarqube servers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extract of a [default `ansible.cfg` file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ansible/ansible/devel/examples/ansible.cfg):

```
# if inventory variables overlap, does the higher precedence one win
# or are hash values merged together?  The default is 'replace' but
# this can also be set to 'merge'.
#hash_behaviour = replace
```

You can therefore change this behavior by setting `hash_behaviour = merge`.

I would not change that on a system wide basis as it might break other projects/roles that would rely on a default behavior. You can distribute the `ansible.cfg` at the root of your specific project that really needs this.

Meanwhile, as @dgw pointed out with a specific example, I've always been able to keep the default behavior by carefully choosing where to place my variables (group or host in inventory, included file, playbook...) and eventually merge them myself if needed.